# Can I freely drag-resize events to be arbitrary lengths in fullCalendar agenda view

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to display an agendaDay view with hour spaced slots. However I also want to events that are arbitrary lengths. If something takes an hour and 5 minutes then I want it to display as an hour and 5 minutes. At the minute drag resizing snaps to the next available slot.

**how can I disable this snap drag behaviour and allow users to set events of arbitrary length?**

This doesn't seem to be that unusual a use case to me, how have other people solved this?

---

Things I've tried:

Setting the slotMinutes to a low value such as 5. This helps with resizing but also makes the default event length 5 minutes. Also it takes up alot of space. I tried reducing the height of the slots to 1px which works to an extent but the drag action becomes untethered from the timescale. Also the calculation of the clicked time becomes wildly inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a programmatic solution, but I think this is a problem best solved by a second edit screen for the event.

Take a look at Google Calendar, you drag events to the nearest size (often the divisions work out well for *most* events) ... and then you edit the event giving a specific start/end time on a second page.

Other than that ... when you say arbitrary length, you mean 1 minute precision I assume - so then you essentially need slots of 1 minute. Not sure how cumbersome that will be for the user. You could have 1 min slots and then only display the time on the left hand side every half hour. Not sure where in the code this would be, but try having a look in /src/agenda/AgendaView.js